# Hardcode layout params into XML or implement programatically in code for consistent UI?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

I want to ensure a consistent UI across all screen sizes. I'll use the bottom margin as an example. Let me illustrate with the picture below:

[image]

I could hardcode 50dp into the xml for the bottom margin as shown in the picture and treat it as a "middle ground" between large and small devices. Or, I could determine dynamically on runtime the parent view's height, and then multiply it with, say, 10 % and then implement it that way although it's a bit more of a hassle. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to set margins as percentage for a beautiful UI. Margins should stay same as long as you are not showing different UIs for different screen sizes.

Using XML for dimensions is generally the best way. It helps you to keep the code clean. If you need different values for different cases (such as device size, orientation, density), you can use variations of XML files (e.g. values-large for larger screen sizes). Just don't include hard-coded values in your layout XML, try to extract them into values files. For example use a layout XML like:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom" />
```

and create two dimens.xml files under values and values-large folders:

values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin_bottom">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-large/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin_bottom">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to give a margin in xml, also you can specify a bigger one for tablets in `layout-sw600dp/` and `layout-sw720dp/`.

Btw, you don't need to dynamically determine the height of the screen in your second approach. You can specify a parent `linear layout` with orientation `vertical` and with a `weightSum = 10` for example. Then you create your child views with `layout_weight`s (the sum of weights should be 9.5 in this example), and for the bottom margin you can create an empty `view` with 0.5 `layout_weight`. So this way, the ratio will be fine on every screen.